# How to `use` variables inside a closure created with `Closure::fromCallback()`?

Tags: php, scope, closures, callable-object

Does PHP support `use`ing a local variable inside the scope of a `Closure` even when this one is created via `Closure::fromCallable()` ?

Usually I'd do

```
$value = 'foobar';
$callback = function() use (&$value) {
    $value .= ' string';
    return $value;
};
var_export($callback());  // prints 'foobar string'
```

But how do I obtain the same when having more complex code?

```
class A
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $value = 'foobar';
        $callback = Closure::fromCallable([ $this, 'myCallable' ]);

        var_export( $callback() );
    }

    protected function myCallable()
    {
        $value .= ' string';
        return $value;
    }
}
```

I know in this case I could just pass the value as callable argument, but I am writing because of curiosity about how PHP works.

Also, yes, it's pretty nonsense to use $value inside `myCallable` without having declared it anywhere. But still, it's more about curiosity than correctness

I already tried `$callback = Closure::fromCallable([ $this, 'myCallable' ]) use ($value);` but it fails with a syntax error.

Shouldn't the `fromCallable` method support passing the variables that we want in the closure's scope, replacing the functionality of the `use` statement?

I can't find any insight in [functions.anonymous](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) or [closure.fromcallable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/closure.fromcallable.php).

Comment: I can see a problem is that `use` allows access to the scope encapsulating the call - but a closure could be defined in method A (so the `use` is defined in A) and then called in method B - so which scope does it use.

Comment: Legit observation ... 

Answer (score 1):

What if you can resolve it this way :

```
class A
{
    private $value;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->value = 'foobar';
        $callback = Closure::fromCallable([ $this, 'myCallable'  ]);

        var_export( $callback() );
    }

    protected function myCallable()
    {
        $this->value .= ' string'; 
        return $this->value;
    }
}
```